# Продать приложение вместе с аккаунтом - как это?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development

Всем привет, проконсультируйте пожалуйста.
Такая ситуация: в моем аккаунте разработчика сейчас 2 опубликованных приложения, со скачками и отзывами.
Одно из них хотят купить, вместе с аккаунтом разработчика.
Вопрос: как быть с вторым? 
Я так понимаю, что его нужно оттуда удалять и публиковать в новом созданном аккаунте?

А вообще, это норм практика, что приложение хотят купить с аккаунтом разраба?

Comment: Я бы не продавал аккаунт, почему? Потому что если на нём будущие владельцы схватят бан, есть вероятность, что все твои остальные аккаунты просто забанят в след за проданным.

Comment: Вам легче создать второй аккаунт, перенести туда приложение для продажи и продать этот "пакет".

Comment: Предполагаю цель покупки вместе с аккаунтом в то что здесь есть определённый рейтинг (скачевания, рейтинг, комменты и т.д.), а на новом акке его нужно раскручивать, и не факт что оно так просто будет догнать то того же значения. Если они и согласятся на такую сделку то будет она явно дешевле. Здесь лучше покурить доку или проконсультироваться у самого гугла, можно ли передать кому либо свой акк на PlayMarkete что бы он не был ассоциирован с вами в будущем. Я думаю что-то подобное должно быть. Это рынок. Тут сотни проектов, которые создаются только что бы быть проданными.

Answer (score 0):

Продавать аккаунт с приложением плохая идея
Можешь поймать бан и на остальные в случае бана этого

Лучше перенеси приложение на другой аккаунт (на аккаунт покупателя)
Для этого просто скрой его на своем, измени имя пакета и залей на аккаунт покупателя
Готово